# PowerShell (?) Check office 365 mailbox and forward emails to another system by reset API

Tags: powershell, rest, api, office365, office365api

I would love to have guidance as to the right way to do it.

I have to forward emails from Office 365 mailbox to another system by reset API.
The format of email is something like that:

```js
Subject: TELLA SERVICE
Body: 
Computer: TELLA
ERROR: STOP WORKING
```

It is also necessary to change the format of the email to something like this:

```js
hostname = body>computer
service = subject
Description = Body>Error
```

I understand that the easy way to do this is with PowerShell. is it true?
And the steps are:

1. Connect to O365 and check the mailbox
2. Check if there is new emails
3. converter it to json with this settings ( hostname=body>computer, service=subject, description= body>error)
4. send the json by rest api

I'm new to the world of PowerShell and working with APIs, and if there is a template that I can start working on it will be very helpful..

Thank you

Meni

Answer (score 0):

Working with O365, I normally would use a mailbox rule to do the forwarding.  I'm sure that it can be done with a PowerApp also.  As much as I love doing everything in PowerShell, I don't think it's the easiest way to do that.